# Watson Assistant finds correct Intent and correct Entity but responds from incorrect dialog

Tags: ibm-watson, watson-assistant

I've built a basic music-playing bot with Watson Assistant. I have a parent node for genre and a set of child nodes for artist selection. This all works as expected first time through the dialog. But when I attempt to request a different artist, Watson recognizes the correct Intent and the correct Entity, yet it instead responds from the Anything Else dialog repeatedly. I'm attaching a screen cap to illustrate.[image]

Comment: What is the flow after the dialog node was picked the first time? Do you jump back to welcome and process the response?

Comment: @data_henrik I'm not following your question (no pun intended). Which dialog node are you referring to as 'the first time'? You can see that I had a successful response of Miles Davis, and then when I asked for a different artist in the same category, it jumped to Anything else.

Comment: When processing for the node "choose jazz artist" is done, what is the set option on how to continue? Wait for user input, jump to another node, skip...?

Comment: 'Wait for reply'

Comment: Ok, try to set it to "jump to and respond" and select the "welcome" node. Give it a try

Comment: That doesn't work. Same result.

Answer (score 0):

The first time you run through the dialog the context will be clean. On subsequent turns the dialog will have built context. Without seeing the logic around your dialog flow it is difficult to pin down which bit of context, but something in the context will be blocking the flow from going down this dialog leg.

Comment: when you say 'context' are you referring specifically to context variables or to something else?

Comment: Both context variables and current position in the dialog.

Comment: I've actually got beyond this initial problem. The issue I have now is that I'm not able to delete context variables that have been set in the correct place apparently. i.e. when a user loops back to ask the same question and give a different answer, either the previous value is preserved, or the variable is not available at all. I've tried editing the JSON in multiple ways but still no success.